# How to replace a value of a key in a object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Him I am new to the `react redux`. I have an array of objects which is like,

```
let result = [ {Id :'a',temp:5,data:'abc (c:1'},{Id :'a',temp:5,data:'pqr (c:1'}{Id :'a',temp:5,data:'xyz (c:1'}]
```

Now, what I want to do is that there is  key called `data` with some value, I want to take the value which is before that bracket only in that data key.

what I want to look an object ,

```
{Id :'a',count:5,data:'abc'}
```

what I have is , 
I have an regex which I use to get that value,

and I have used for loop ,

```
for (let i = 0; i <= result.length - 1; i++) {
         let regex = /^[^\(]+/;
         let value = data.match(regex)[0].trim();
        result[i].data = value 
      }


fetchQuestions() {
    let previous_data = { ...this.props.data  };
    let result = [];
    for (let key in previous_data) {
      result = [...result, ...previous_data[key]];
    }
    for (let i = 0; i <= result.length - 1; i++) {
      let regex = /^(.*)\(/;
      let value = result[i].technology.match(regex)[1].trim();
      result[i].technology = value;
    }
    this.props.fetchQuestions(result);
  }
```

In this `this.props.data` is the reducer data .Now what I want to do was, I have to get some data from this and do some manipulation. but here, it is directly updating my reducer values itself, But I have used spread operator to get the copy of that data ,but still its updating the reducers values.

But I am not getting the value which I expect. Can any one help me with this ?

Comment: try this - let regex =/^(\w+)/;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a regex that creates a group for the value before `(` and then get it from the match

```js
let result= [
  {
    Id: 'a',
    temp: 5,
    data: 'abc (c:1'
  },
  {
    Id: 'a',
    temp: 5,
    data: 'pqr (c:1'
  },
  {
    Id: 'a',
    temp: 5,
    data: 'xyz (c:1'
  }
]
for (let i = 0; i <= result.length - 1; i++) {
         let regex = /^(.*)\(/;
         let value = result[i].data.match(regex)[1].trim();
        result[i].data = value 
    }
    
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Using this regex I am getting a bracket in the data value

Comment: and If I use 1 then it gives null. I think it should be 0

Comment: Hey @shubham I got so many solutions, Which one will be more efficient

Comment: @ganeshk, the index will be 1 to get the first group match. Also a regex solution will be more efficient than a string manipulation using split. 

Any regex from the solutions that satisfies your use case should be good enough for you

Comment: I have just updated my question,On reducer value is getting updated , But It should not get update with

Comment: You should make use of map instead of for loop to  get the updated value

Comment: But , why is it updating the main reducers values I mean this.props.data, as I am making a copy of that and manipulating that copy only

Comment: spread syntax performs a shallow copy of the array and not the deep copy, hence it is getting updated

Comment: How should I create a deep copy ? using object.assign ?

Comment: Both object.assign and spread perform a one level copy. Make use of map to return the shallow copy objects using spread

Comment: Can you give me a bit example kind of ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to access the `data` property of each object while you're iterating, in order to use a `.match` on it:

```js
let result = [{
  Id: 'a',
  temp: 5,
  data: 'abc (c:1'
}, {
  Id: 'a',
  temp: 5,
  data: 'pqr (c:1'
}, {
  Id: 'a',
  temp: 5,
  data: 'xyz (c:1'
}];
for (let i = 0; i <= result.length - 1; i++) {
  const { data } = result[i];
  let regex = /^[^\(]+/;
  let value = data.match(regex)[0].trim();
  result[i].data = value;
}
console.log(result);
```

But, seeing as you're using react, you might consider using `.map` instead, which won't mutate the original objects:

```js
let result = [{
  Id: 'a',
  temp: 5,
  data: 'abc (c:1'
}, {
  Id: 'a',
  temp: 5,
  data: 'pqr (c:1'
}, {
  Id: 'a',
  temp: 5,
  data: 'xyz (c:1'
}];
console.log(
  result.map(({ data, ...rest }) => ({
    data: data.match(/^[^(]+[^( ]/)[0],
    ...rest
  }))
);
```

Note that if you make the final matched character in the regex `[^( ]` (match anything but a `(` or a space), there's no need for `trim` anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split('(')` instead of regex to get the same output:

```js
let result = [{
  Id: 'a',
  temp: 5,
  data: 'abc (c:1'
}, {
  Id: 'a',
  temp: 5,
  data: 'pqr (c:1'
}, {
  Id: 'a',
  temp: 5,
  data: 'xyz (c:1'
}];
for (let i = 0; i <= result.length - 1; i++) {
  let value = result[i].data.split('(')[0].trim();
  result[i].data = value
}
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
  result.map(el => {
        el.data = el.data.match(/^(\w+)/)[0];
        return el;
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let result = [ {Id :'a',temp:5,data:'abc (c:1'},{Id :'a',temp:5,data:'pqr (c:1'},{Id :'a',temp:5,data:'xyz (c:1'}]

const new_result = result.map((item) => {
    let regex = /^[^\(]+/;
  let value = item.data.match(regex)[0].trim();
  item.data = value;
  return item;
});

console.log(new_result);
```